# Cannot Delete Folder Links in Explorer

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-explorer

I am trying to delete what looks like folders, but are actually links to non-existent folders in Explorer:

[image: System Folders]

I tried copying the address and searching in Regedit, but when I tried to delete the registry key it wouldn't let me or let me change permissions.

[image: Folder Path]

Any ideas how to delete these?